# RPI docker running ubuntu container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, raspberry-pi

I recently installed `docker` in my `raspberry pi` as explained in [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/). I use `docker` in my every day, however never before with the raspberries. It exists an image of the raspberry pi called `resin/rpi-raspbian`. My question comes regarding other containers with other operating systems. Let's say I run in my raspberry:

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu
```

It seems to run perfectly fine. My question is? Is there a problem when doing this? Since `ubuntu` is not meant to run with `armv7l` (maybe I'm mistaken) based systems as the one used in the raspberry. Is this taken into account with the kernel isolation used by `docker`? Are there any consequences, drawbacks or something that might not work because of this?

The question might be silly, but I'm confused about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, if it is working, then it works!

Docker isolates the image and runs it in a container, over the existing kernel (It shares some part with the existing kernel). The idea behind this is to eliminate the dependencies of OS/ kernel version for different applications. Docker provides you that environment, so that your application can freely run upon it. The same applies to all of the Operating systems you want to run on docker. It takes care of them for you. Cheers!